# Template hierarchy changes when custom post-type permalink leverages custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite

I've got a custom post type `departments` with a custom taxonomy `department` and am using [Custom Post Type Permalinks plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/). In the CPT, I define the permalink like this:

```
'rewrite' => array(
  'slug' => 'departments',
  'with_front' => false
)
```

The permalink looks like `/departments/article-name-here` and the template I can use to modify it's look is here: `single-departments.php`. This works correctly.

But if I change my permalink for the CPT to use my custom taxonomy in the rewrite rule like this:

```
'rewrite' => array(
  'slug' => '%department%',
  'with_front' => false
)
```

The permalink now looks right: `/department-name/article-name-here` but `single-departments.php` doesn't work anymore. In fact, I can't setup a template naming structure that picks it up - I've tried all of them that I normally would use. I have flushed permalinks with each test via admin panel.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You normally can't define a slug like that, the format clashes with the built in `page` rewrite rules.

Comment: @milo - whats the right way to do this?